# Octave: Find mean in a column but only for matching values

Tags: matrix, encoding, octave

I'm working on an extended matrix in octave where the final column is the label that states which centroid that data point is closest to. I know I need to use the mean function but am unsure how to select only specific values within the column that I need.

For example:

column 1    column 2   ...   ...   ...   etc... label column -> (is the last column)
info        .....     ...   ...   ...   ...       1
...         ....      ...    ...   ...    ...      2
...          ...       ...    ...   ...    ...      1
...         ...       ...    ...   ...    ...       3
....        ....       ...    ...   ...    ...      4

I would only want to pick the rows that are labeled 1 so that I could update their centroid, so when it is graphed they would all be clustered together in a group where 2, 3, and 4 would have each grouping of their own.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Do you want to know how to find the rows with last column value as `1`? or do you want to find `mean`? Please share an example of a sample matrix with actual values along with your exact expected resultant matrix. Please read  [Index Expressions](https://octave.org/doc/v6.4.0/Index-Expressions.html) and  [Advanced Indexing](https://octave.org/doc/v6.4.0/Advanced-Indexing.html)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Your example does not format into a matrix when viewed on a mobile device. Please replace it with an actual sample data, format it as code, and then supply what a desired output would look like. then we might be able to help you get from one to the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
>> m = randi(9,10,4)
m =
   3   8   5   1
   6   6   7   9
   5   4   9   8
   5   7   1   1
   3   8   8   4
   6   5   1   6
   2   9   9   2
   4   6   4   7
   4   4   1   1
   8   1   1   9

>> m(m(:,end)==1,:)
ans =
   3   8   5   1
   5   7   1   1
   4   4   1   1
```

Comment: Then, as a general rule, could you please formally validate the answer, to show in the SO search engine that no more answer is expected for this query? Thanks

Comment: I don't know how to do that, sorry

Comment: There is a validation check symbol to click, below the count of votes for the answer. You can see validated answers as examples: in the SO list of questions, any question that has a validated answer is listed with a full green background of the counter of answers. Choose such a question ; see where the validation mark is set ; and then do the same for answers you want to validate for your own questions.